# foreverjs doesn't write console.log of the child process to log files

Tags: javascript, npm, forever

I have a nodejs server running which polls data using `setInterval` function every x seconds. This bit of the app looks like this:

```js
startPolling () {
    debug('Snmp poller started');

    timers.setInterval(
        this.poll(),
        config.get('Snmp.interval')
);
}

poll () {
    return () => {
        if (dbConnection.get()) {
            debug('Polling data');
            this.fetchSiteNodes(this.site);
        }
    };
}
```

Next in my `pacakge.json` file I'm running the server with this lengthy command:

> NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./ NODE_ENV=development
>   forever -p logs -a -l forever.log -o logs/output.log -e
>   logs/error.log -d start ./bin/www

I'll break it down here :

- -p logs - path to the `logs` directory where I want all the logs to sit
- -a - add logs at the end of `forever.log` file
- -l forever.log - name of the log file to write to
- -o logs/output.log - name of the file where stdout goes (if I'm not mistaken ?)
- -e logs/error.log - name of the file where all error from the child process goes
- -d - debug mode ? (more verbose debug?)
- start - starting forever

Now from the code snippet above and the forever command I would expect that the `logs/output.log` file would contain all the `console.logs(...)` outputs from the script so it would contains something like this:

```
Snmp poller started
polling data +10
// after 10 secons 
polling data +10
```

Unfortunately this is not what is happening, basically all the log files stay empty.

How do I make the child process write the `console.logs` to the `output.log` file of forever process ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I missed the fact I'm using [debug library](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) and I haven't included level of debugging in the npm command, after adding `DEBUG=server,app,database` it started working as expected. Eventually I could also add `DEBUG=*` but then the output is overwhelming containing all mongodb queries etc.